# Position function resulting in warning

Tags: r, analytics

I m a beginner to R in data analysis context. And here i had to stop as i cant position any of my data. A warning appears but nothing displays.Its just like the position function only doesn't work.

```
qplot(cty,hwy,data=mpg,position = "jitter")
Warning message:
`position` is deprecated
```

Comment: It is not about the jitter only. The problem is that whenever i use position function it results in  warning.                                            qplot(color, data = diamonds, fill = cut, position = "dodge") 
Warning message:
`position` is deprecated     And the default geom="bar" diagram appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning says  `position` is deprecated. Instead of 
`position="jitter"` use `geom="jitter"`